# Magento Upgrade 1.7 to 1.8 + onepage checkout issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Unfortunately it is still on a test local server so providing any browsable links are not possible at the moment. But I will try to describe my problem as clearly and specifically as I can.
This has been reported quite a few places on the Magentocommerce forum too. Their solutions - adding an id to payment.phtml, some javascript code on info.phtml, updating checkout.xml did not work for me yet. That is the reason I resort to asking this question here and one other reason is as I am typing this, Magento forum is spammed to death.

**So my problem is:** 
After upgrading to 1.8 from 1.7.x:

On **onepage checkout**, I get to the payment methods section and have Bank transfer, Payone, Credit card etc. selectable. I want to make a simple Bank transfer selection and proceed. I can straightaway see that there's **no details of the bank** (*although I have them entered on the backend*) displayed when I select the option. Similar with Payone, Klarna etc. I select one and move forward (I can proceed) to review step and I see that the **progress/summary** on the right does not show me any payment method. I can still proceed and complete but when I do that, I get nothing on the payment method section of the transaction email.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Try checking your templatefiles for a form_key. Since 1.8, Magento added frontend form validation... It could be that custom templates are not 1.8 ready.

Comment: I have compared templates with the default templates. They are not so different. Plus, my onepage checkout related templates are still most of them default. And I compared it with a 1.9 installation, there was no form_key either. :(

Comment: compare file with 1.7 your old theme and new to update with 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the `<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">` and the javascript code solution, I have an earlier 1.7.x version running smoothly **without** these codes and ids.

I resolved my problem with these steps:

I compared my theme against a working one and figured out that somehow my **default** as well as 1.8-1.9 compatible theme both missed out on a folder called **bankprepayment** with an **info.phtml** and **form.phtml** file inside.

I copied it to my theme folder (could also copy it simply to default magento theme because it is **missing** there too) and it started working now.

**This particular fix solved my problem because of the following:**

- I do not install **Bank Prepayment** manually or intentionally because it installs on my system bundled with **German MarketReady**.
- The template I bought although is up to 1.9 compatible, but for any template builder, it is impossible to test every combination of extensions on a system.
- These probably happened because the during the installation, somewhere it failed on copying/making the required folder and files and was never reported.

I have reported the issue already to the template builder as well as German MarketReady community and I hope it is resolved in the next fixes.

Answer (score 5):

I had also the checkout issue and I have found the solution:

In /template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml (at the end)

replace

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

by

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

> /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR-THEME/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

AND

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Line number 36

```
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
```

Replace with

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
```

It should resolve your checkout issue.

there have small form key change issue use win merge and compare old and new file.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, but I already mentioned briefly in my question that those  did not solve my problem. I have found a solution and am posting the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for this. If you're using enterprise, and you have the line `<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('methods_additional', '', true, true) ?>`, make sure to put that outside this new `<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">`, or it will wipe out the ability to use store credit. Took me about a day to figure that out.